# How can I give extra compiler parameters with SIP 5?

Tags: python-3.x, python-sip

Trying to build Python bindings with SIP 5. But I can't figure out how I pass parameters to the compiler.

In SIP 4.x, there could be extra options to the compiler set in `configure.py` by doing

```
makefile = sipconfig.SIPModuleMakefile(config, build_file)

makefile.extra_libs = ["foo"]
makefile.extra_cxxflags = ["-std=c++17"]
```

With SIP 5 I can't figure out how I can do the same, since `configure.py` no longer is a part of it.

I have looked through, and search the docs, but to no avail.

Now I get warnings like
`warning: scoped enumerations are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]`

I wish to pass the right parameters to the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is done via the `pyproject.toml` file under the Bindings section.

https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/sip/pyproject_toml.html#bindings-sections

There is parameter `extra-compile-args` and `libraries` that may do what you want.